# Variables in JSON URL String Android

Tags: android, json, variables

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction with this. Somewhat new to Android so hang in there if I am just totally missing something silly. I have been tearing my hair out over this.
I create a string that gets sent to a service handler to grab json information. 
The problem is I can send it no problem if the json url is hardcoded in. 
like this :  String url = "google.com"
but when I try to put variables in the url like this : String url = "www.google.com/" + file; 
it chokes. 
I have tried darn near everything I can think of.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
Attached is my code snippet.

```html
  String url = "http://mapp.snc.edu/cgi-bin/ma/classes/" + subs + "";  
  
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
        
        
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        try {
          // Getting JSON Array
          term = json.getJSONArray(TAG_TERM);
          JSONObject c = term.getJSONObject(0);
          // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
          String termdesc = c.getString(TAG_ID);

          //Importing TextView
          final TextView uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.header);
          
          //Set JSON Data in TextView
          uid.setText(termdesc);
          
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: what is the actual error or problem you are facing?

Comment: The entire app crashes when I am using the variables in the url.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am trying to get the disgustingly slow emulator to work. Will post shortly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpClient to add variables:

```
try{
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

       HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
       request.setURI(new URI("your main website"););

       ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yourkey1", yourvalue1)); 
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yourkey2", yourvalue2));  etc...

       request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  //Add parameters to connection

       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

       String jsonString = response.getEntity().getContent().toString();
       (...)
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
   }
```